# Why does Anorm throw a TypeDoesNotMatch exception when inserting a Primary Key as Text?

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm, postgresql-9.4

I have a table in Postgres 9.4 that has email address as the Primary Key.  Using Anorm, I then carry out the following

```
 DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL"insert into member_login_email(email, password) values ($email, $password)".executeInsert()
}
```

When this is executed, the correct values are entered into the table, but a TypeDoesNotMatch runtime exception is thrown:

```
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert dsfsfadsf@ddd.com: class java.lang.String to Long for column ColumnName(member_login_email.email,Some(email)))
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
    at anorm.Sql$.anorm$Sql$$as(Anorm.scala:472) ~[anorm_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at anorm.Sql$class.executeInsert(Anorm.scala:350) ~[anorm_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at anorm.SimpleSql.executeInsert(Anorm.scala:190) ~[anorm_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at repository.MemberLoginEmailRepository$$anonfun$create$1.apply(MemberLoginEmailRepository.scala:17) ~[classes/:na]
```

It seems that Anorm is expecting Primary Keys to be of type Long.  Is there anyway of getting Anorm to accept a Primary Key of type Text without throwing an exception?

I've looked at the [source code for Anorm](https://github.com/playframework/anorm) but have been struggling to see where this is actually happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, `executeInsert()` is using a `ResultSetParser[Option[Long]]` to parse the primary key returned from the database. As seen from the [scaladocs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#anorm.Sql):

```
def executeInsert[A](generatedKeysParser: ResultSetParser[A] = SqlParser.scalar[Long].singleOpt)
```

To make this work with a `String` primary key, you would use this instead:

```
executeInsert(SqlParser.scalar[String].singleOpt)
```

This will return an `Option[String]`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I'll accept this answer in 6 minutes once the StackOverflow arbitrary limit allows me to.